# Dynamic scenario dispatcher for Python Behave

Tags: python, bdd, scenarios, python-behave

I am running multiple scenarios and would like to incorporate some sort of dynamic scenario dispatcher which would allow me to have specific steps to execute after a test is done based on the scenario executed. When I was using PHPUnit, I used to be able to subclass the TestCase class and add my own setup and teardown methods. For behave, what I have been doing is adding an extra "Then" step at the end of the scenario which would be executed once the scenario finishes to clean up everything - clean up the configuration changes made by scenario, etc. But since every scenario is different, the configuration changes I need to make are specific to a scenario so I can't use the after_scenario hook that I have in my environment.py file. Any ideas on how to implement something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`after_scenario` passes both the scenario to the function. You can then dispatch on the scenario name or any of its tags. For example, with tags, you could define your scenario as

```
@clean_up
Scenario: Something
    ...
```

And your after listener as

```
def after_scenario(context, scenario):
    if 'clean_up' in scenario.tags:
        ...
    elif 'clean_down' in scenario.tags:
        ...
```

Comment: That is what I had in mind initially, but I have too many variations of the tear down method. How to make it more scalable?

Comment: If you're trying to tear down what's in the context, you can check if it exists in the context, and then do whatever cleanup you need there. For example, check `hasattr(context, 'thing_you_want_cleaned_up')`

Comment: Hmmm what I was thinking is I would like to perform specific teardown methods on different scenarios. Basically, same as the code you posted in the question but I'd like it to scale (e.g. for 30 different teardown methods that I would like, this would require 30 different tags and would mean the after_scenario function would be at least 30 lines?)

Answer (score 0):

What I've been doing might give you an idea:

In the before_all specify a list in the context (eg context.teardown_items =[]).

Then in the various steps of various scenarios add to that list (accounts, orders or whatever)

Then in the after_all I login as a superuser and clean everything up I specified in that list.

Could something like that work for you ?